# Dangers of shifting a char out of scope

Tags: c++, byte-shifting

Okay,

I wrote a function that takes an unsigned char from a hex file and then shifts it to the left to fit inside a WORD,DWORD or QWORD, like follows:

```
retVal |= ((unsigned char)(memory[i]) << (8 * j));
```

(inside a loop, hence variables i and j).

Now visual studio reminds me of possible arithmetik overflow.

My question: If I limit j to be never more than 8 (size of a uint64_t), can I safely ignore this message?
I am always a little bummed about warnings and try to eliminate them.

In my understanding it should not matter how much you shift to the left before saving the value, am I mistaken?

EDIT:

here is an example (it's my function):

```
int getValuePNTR(const char* memory, int &start, int size)
{
    uint64_t retVal = 0;

    //now just add up array fields 
    for (int i = start + size-1,j = size-1; j >= 0; --j, i--)
    {
        //fprintf(stdout, "\ncycle: %d, memory: [%x]", j, memory[i]);

        if ((unsigned char)memory[i] == 00 && j > 0)
            retVal <<= 8;
        else
            retVal |= ((unsigned char)(memory[i]) << (8 * j));
    }
    //get the next field after this one
    start += size;
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: For cases when `j` equals `8`, what bit position will the originally 7th bit occupy?

Comment: How confident are you that your compiler is warning you about the left shift operation, and not about the `|=` operator? Or, how confident are you that your compiler is not warning you about an overflow due to the left-handside getting promoted only to `int`, which is likely to be only a 32 bit value, and not a 64 bit value as you're assuming?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the warning. Can you share a [MCVE]? Are you sure that this line is the one that is producing a warning?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik as you can see, I'm using a uint64_t , not a normal DWORD

Comment: Hm, you wrote that comment ***after*** the answer was already posted, which clearly explained the error in your understanding of integer promotion rules. No, you are not using 64 bit values in the shift operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to limit `(8 * j)` to be less than `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` in order to keep you code legal in all cases (assuming a standard x86-64 implementation).

First, when you do `(unsigned char)(memory[i]) << (8 * j)` integer promotion happens and then type of the expression is the type of the promoted left hand side.  In this case `unsigned char` is promoted to `int` if `sizeof(unsigned char) < sizeof(int)` and `unsigned int` otherwise.

Then [[expr.shift]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.shift#1) has

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand.

Which is the reason why `(8 * j)` needs to be less than `sizeof(promoted_type) * CHAR_BIT`

Comment: okay, I have a limit build in, I expanded the question to include actual code. I have macros for the size-argument, and the biggest value it can take per makro is 8. so, if i understood you correctly, this should be fine then?

Comment: @clockw0rk it depends on what `j` will be.  For your platform `8 * j` needs to be less than 32 or you'll have undefined behavior.